# Obstime Syntax for AstroPy? Python UTC time for coordinate conversion

Tags: python, python-2.7, time, datetime-format, astropy

I am trying to use AstroPy to convert coordinates for a satellite from ECI to Latitude, Longitude, and Altitude at a given time. However, I cannot get the time part to work with AstroPy obstime. I'm not sure if it's a syntax error for the UTC time or something else.

```
'New Method #1: ECI --> Lat, Lon, Alt'
from astropy import coordinates as coord
from astropy import units as u
from astropy import time
from astropy.time import Time

xyz = (orbitPineapple.r.x, orbitPineapple.r.y, orbitPineapple.r.z)      #position of satellite in GCRS or J2000 ECI
now = time.Time('2017-09-28 16:53:40') #Time in UTC for xyz
cartrep = coord.CartesianRepresentation(*xyz, unit=u.m) #adding units of [m] to xyz

gcrs = coord.GCRS(cartrep, obstime=now)
itrs = gcrs.transform_to(coord.ITRS, obstime=now)
loc = coord.EarthLocation(*itrs.cartesian.xyz)

print(orbitPineapple.r)
print('')
print(loc.lat, loc.lon, loc.height)
```

My inputs: (Position(x=-2686197.0596728502, y=-6402017.6107924329, z=10956.564679617248))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is similar to the answer to your previous question [How to convert Earth Centered Inertial (ECI) coordinates to Earth Centered Earth Fixed (ECEF) AstroPy? Other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46433702/how-to-convert-earth-centered-inertial-eci-coordinates-to-earth-centered-earth)

`obstime` needs to be passed to the `ITRS()` class:

```
itrs = gcrs.transform_to(coord.ITRS(obstime=now))
```

So, in full (I copied the xyz coordinates from your question because I don't see a definition for `orbitPineapple`)

```
from astropy import coordinates as coord
from astropy import units as u
from astropy import time
from astropy.time import Time

xyz = [-2686197.0596728502, -6402017.6107924329, 10956.564679617248]
now = time.Time('2017-09-28 16:53:40') #Time in UTC for xyz
cartrep = coord.CartesianRepresentation(*xyz, unit=u.m) #adding units of [m] to xyz

gcrs = coord.GCRS(cartrep, obstime=now)
itrs = gcrs.transform_to(coord.ITRS(obstime=now))
loc = coord.EarthLocation(*itrs.cartesian.xyz)

print('')
print(loc.lat, loc.lon, loc.height)
```